Book on data science talking about both DNA and RNA
I do not have any eductatin in biology, I am a mathematician. However I am reading a book in data science, and am trying to understad an example involving, DNA, mRNA and genes.
From what I understand we have these concepts:
DNA: This is the double helix molecule that makes up our genetic code. The helix is long and consists of a long code, and the code is made up of four molcules and the order in which the molecules occur is the code
Gene: This is different parts of the DNA.
RNA: This is similar to the DNA, but is a single helix. It also consists of four molecules, but one molecule is different from the DNA.
The relevant text is this:

Question:
The author  want to measure the amount of genes in a cell by measuring the amount of RNA in that gene? However a gene is something that is in DNA? So by this logic something that is in the DNA consists of RNA, but as I noted above, RNA and DNA are built up of 4 molecules, but one differ, so how can this be?

The concept here is which genes are being "read"/ transcribed into mRNA in that cell/tissue.  From Nature.com: "Even though nearly every cell in an organism's body contains the same set of genes, only a fraction of these genes are used in any given cell at any given time. It is this carefully controlled pattern of what is called "gene expression"  that makes a liver cell different from a muscle cell...(The article is very easy to understand and helpful!)

@anongoodnurse Thank you very much! I found this in your article very helpful: "Remember, in order to activate a gene, a cell must first copy the DNA sequence of that gene into a piece of mRNA known as a transcript. Thus, by determining which mRNA transcripts are present in a cell, scientists can determine which genes are expressed in that cell at different stages of development and under different environmental conditions. " I think this answers my question. :) If you want you can put this as an answer, and I will accept.

Unfortunately this is very much a basic biology question, which means it falls under the homework policy, and means it will be closed.

Yes, it's a good article and explains gene expression very well. Thanks for the offer, but I only answer in comments when I know the question will be closed, and think the OP can use a bit of help. :) (I stink at math, so maybe someday, you'll pay it forward for someone like me.)
